# Using ZeroMQ on Infiniband SDP

Tags: sockets, select, zeromq, sdp, infiniband

I am trying to run the ZeroMQ's `local_thr/remote_thr` on SDP (infiniband) compiled on MSVS2012. But it's not connecting.

On IPoIB it is working properly. Operating System is Windows Server 2008 R2. On further investigation I found out that `select()` calls within ZeroMQ libraries are not working for Asynch `accept()` and `send()`. 
I also created a test application using BSD socket API and used `select` to accept connection on non blocking socket. But `select`is not receiving the event for `accept`.

Please let me know what can be done to troubleshoot this issue.